# how to put a python dictionary in a protobuf message?

Tags: python, json, protocol-buffers

Suppose we have this Json blob:

```
{
  "thing": {
    "x": 1,
    "str": "hello,
    "params": {
      "opaque": "yes",
      "unknown": 1,
      "more": ...
    }
  }
}
```

The contents of params is unknown. All we know is that it's a dictionary.
How do we define a protobuf message that can parse it?

```
// file: thing.proto
message Thing {
    uint32 x = 1;
    string str = 2;
    WhatGoesHere? params = 3;
}
```

[Edit] Moved solution to answer as per comment.

Comment: python is dynamically typed you do not have to, and cannot, declare variables such as `uint32 x = 1` or `string str = 2`, also you do not need to end your statements with semicolons

Comment: @0TTT0 thanks but ... the message Thing is from a .proto file. (will update post.)

Comment: @timmer thanks for this, unfortunately it doesn't work well if you care about ints vs floats for example. It seems that Struct, ListValue and Value are all designed for the purpose of translating to JSON, so ints and floats get grouped together as "number". If anyone has found a better way to serialise and deserialise a python dict without writing lots of bespoke code, please let me know!!

Comment: If you found a solution (or two), please put them into an answer instead of adding them to the question. Then you can accept the answer, and your question no longer appears in the list of unanswered questions - where I just found it.

Comment: @RolandWeber solution moved to answer. it's been a while. i'm sure i had a good reason for editing the question instead of posting an answer. ;->

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solutions: Use google provided messages.

```
// file: solution.proto
import "google/protobuf/struct.proto";

message Solution1 {
    uint32 x = 1;
    string str = 2;
    google.protobuf.Struct params = 3;
}

message Solution2 {
    uint32 x = 1;
    string str = 2;
    map<string, google.protobuf.Value> params = 3;
}
```

Comment: You cannot simply assign a dictionary value to params (Solution 1) - it errors out. You have to do params.update(my_dict) The 2nd solution is missing some imports